# links suddenly stopped working

Tags: html, hyperlink

[Live site.](http://zoparealty.com/)

I've been working on this site for a while, and after a brief hiatus have returned to find that the three social media links in the footer have stopped working. All other links on the page, including the other links in the footer, still work as intended. I'm puzzled because the code hasn't been touched(to my knowledge) and it was working perfectly before the hiatus.

Any ideas what could be going on?

```
<div class="social">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/ZOPArealty"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/twitter.png" alt="ZOPA%20Twitter" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/ZopaRealty"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/facebook.png" alt="ZOPA%20Facebook" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/zopa-realty"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/linkedin.png" alt="ZOPA%20Linkedin" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end social -->
```

Comment: Did you log get_template_directory_uri() and see if the images actually exist?

Comment: @cggaurav If you look on the page they are clearly there.

Comment: @cggaurav the images exist, they appear on the site, it's the actual action of linking to another site that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `position: relative;` to your `.social` class. This works for me as a quick bugfix.

```
.social {
   position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some crazy floating of elements going on. I put `overflow: hidden;` on `div class="social"`, which fixes the links but breaks your layout.

## EDIT

The culprit seems to be that the `li`'s are floated to the left. Since you have `display: inline` on those, you could take out the `float: left` and use relative positioning to fix up your layout.